# Install old Python 3.6 using MSYS2

Tags: msys2, pacman-package-manager

I need to recompile a [library](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-python) using **python 3.6** instead of **python 3.7**. Problem is MSYS2 repository doesn't have but 3.7 version. I hope someone could show me how to install older Python 3.6 using `pacman`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be an easy way to do this. From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages:

> If a package was installed at an earlier stage, and the pacman cache was not cleaned, install an earlier version from /var/cache/pacman/pkg/.
>
> This process will remove the current package and install the older version. Dependency changes will be handled, but pacman will not handle version conflicts. If a library or other package needs to be downgraded with the packages, please be aware that you will have to downgrade this package yourself as well.
>
> ```
> # pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/package-old_version.pkg.tar.xz
> ```
>
> Once the package is reverted, temporarily add it to the IgnorePkg section of pacman.conf, until the difficulty with the updated package is resolved.

MSYS2 also uses the pacman package manager and this seems to be a limitation of that system.

You can, however, download the Python3.6 package from [the MSYS2 package repository](http://repo.msys2.org), but you will need to manually resolve its dependencies and install them using the same method.